# MySQL with InnoDB: How to avoid using COUNT?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, innodb

So I have a table which I populated with ~700K entries for testing, and it is showing it's pain in MySQL queries.

The table in question:

```
CREATE TABLE `trades` (
 `tradeId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `userId` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `visible` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `sourceItem` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `sourceKeyTierId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `sourceKeyTypeId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `sourceKeyAmount` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `sourceModId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `sourceModLevel` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `destinationItem` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `destinationPlatinum` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `destinationKeyTierId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `destinationKeyTypeId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `destinationKeyAmount` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `destinationModId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `destinationModLevel` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `added` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`tradeId`),
 KEY `userId` (`userId`),
 KEY `sourceKeyTierId` (`sourceKeyTierId`),
 KEY `sourceKeyTypeId` (`sourceKeyTypeId`),
 KEY `sourceModId` (`sourceModId`),
 KEY `destinationKeyTierId` (`destinationKeyTierId`),
 KEY `destinationKeyTypeId` (`destinationKeyTypeId`),
 KEY `destinationModId` (`destinationModId`),
 CONSTRAINT `trades_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES `users` (`userId`),
 CONSTRAINT `trades_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`sourceKeyTierId`) REFERENCES `keytiers` (`keyTierId`),
 CONSTRAINT `trades_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`sourceKeyTypeId`) REFERENCES `keytypes` (`keyTypeId`),
 CONSTRAINT `trades_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`sourceModId`) REFERENCES `mods` (`modId`),
 CONSTRAINT `trades_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`destinationKeyTierId`) REFERENCES `keytiers` (`keyTierId`),
 CONSTRAINT `trades_ibfk_6` FOREIGN KEY (`destinationKeyTypeId`) REFERENCES `keytypes` (`keyTypeId`),
 CONSTRAINT `trades_ibfk_7` FOREIGN KEY (`destinationModId`) REFERENCES `mods` (`modId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=732544 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Now when obtaining a result set I want to count the amount of results to decide whether to display a message that no results were found, or not.

```
SELECT SUM(count) AS sum 
FROM
(
  (SELECT COUNT(1) AS count
   FROM trades t
   WHERE t.sourceItem = 1 AND t.destinationItem = 1)
UNION ALL
  (SELECT COUNT(1) AS count
   FROM trades t
   WHERE t.sourceItem = 1 AND t.destinationItem = 2)
UNION ALL
  (SELECT COUNT(1) AS count
   FROM trades t
   WHERE t.sourceItem = 1 AND t.destinationItem = 3)
UNION ALL
  (SELECT COUNT(1) AS count
   FROM trades t
   WHERE t.sourceItem = 2 AND t.destinationItem = 1)
UNION ALL
  (SELECT COUNT(1) AS count
   FROM trades t
   WHERE t.sourceItem = 2 AND t.destinationItem = 2)
UNION ALL
  (SELECT COUNT(1) AS count
   FROM trades t
   WHERE t.sourceItem = 2 AND t.destinationItem = 3)
) AS derived
```

The query is working but it takes 2.63 seconds, which is way to long.

**How would one optimize this?** I thought I had almost done everything I could do, except for one thing:

- As the possible values of `sourceItem` will be `(1, 2)` and the possible values of `destinationItem` will be `(1, 2, 3)`, I could make another table and write via a `TRIGGER ON INSERT` to that table containing the values.

Also not unimportantly, the query is created by a PHP script dependant on POST-variables, which means that every `SELECT` in the `UNION ALL` may or may not be there. Unfortunately this question is not as easy as returning the maximum of the full table.

All other suggestions are also welcome.

**UPDATE:** Appereantly there has been some confusion on how the query is actually constructed, see it as this:

- You have 2 checkboxes for `sourceItem` corresponding to `1` and `2`
- You have 3 checkboxes for `destinationItem` corresponding to `1`, `2` and `3`

The user can check them in any way he wants.

**UPDATE 2:** It seems like my original query will not cut it, even with using indexes, could someone be so kind to think about an entirely different setup that basically eliminates the need for `COUNT` or `SUM` or anything of that sort?

**UPDATE 3:** I have forgot a very important part in my question, which is the following:

- Having `sourceItem = 1` *may* have (`sourceKeyTierId = ?` AND `sourceKeyTypeId` = ?) associated with it
- Having `sourceItem = 2` *may* have (`sourceModId = ?`) associated with it
- Having `destinationItem = 2` *may* have (`destinationKeyTierId = ?` AND `destinationKeyTypeId` = ?) associated with it
- Having `destinationItem = 3` *may* have (`destinationModId = ?`) associated with it

You can still see it in terms of the example with checkboxes, however checking certain checkboxes also leads to the option to input another number (in real scenario it is a select dropdown), which need not to be chosen.

An updated example of my first unoptimized query would be that the following query **could** also occur, but this is the maximal example:

```
SELECT SUM(count) AS sum 
FROM
(
  (SELECT COUNT(1) AS count
   FROM trades t
   WHERE t.sourceItem = 1 AND t.destinationItem = 1 AND t.sourceKeyTierId = ? AND t.sourceKeyTypeId = ?)
UNION ALL
  (SELECT COUNT(1) AS count
   FROM trades t
   WHERE t.sourceItem = 1 AND t.destinationItem = 2 AND t.sourceKeyTierId = ? AND t.sourceKeyTypeId = ? AND t.destinationKeyTierId = ? AND t.destinationKeyTypeId = ?)
UNION ALL
  (SELECT COUNT(1) AS count
   FROM trades t
   WHERE t.sourceItem = 1 AND t.destinationItem = 3 AND t.sourceKeyTierId = ? AND t.sourceKeyTypeId = ? AND t.destinationModId = ?)
UNION ALL
  (SELECT COUNT(1) AS count
   FROM trades t
   WHERE t.sourceItem = 2 AND t.destinationItem = 1 AND t.sourceModId = ?)
UNION ALL
  (SELECT COUNT(1) AS count
   FROM trades t
   WHERE t.sourceItem = 2 AND t.destinationItem = 2 AND t.sourceModId = ? AND t.destinationKeyTierId = ? AND t.destinationKeyTypeId = ?)
UNION ALL
  (SELECT COUNT(1) AS count
   FROM trades t
   WHERE t.sourceItem = 2 AND t.destinationItem = 3 AND t.sourceModId = ? AND t.destinationModId = ?)
) AS derived
```

Comment: As you say `Now when obtaining a result set I want to count the amount of results to decide whether to display a message that no results were found, or not.`  Are you running this query just to check if it will return something or not?

Comment: @Manu Yes, the proceding query is much more advanced (with multiple joins), but also uses a `LIMIT` and `ORDER BY` and contains on average 50 results

Comment: So, you are wanting to know how many results match a particular combination of `sourceItem` and `destinationItem`, when the requested combination to count is not known in advance?  Eg, first query could be "how many <1, 2> or <2, 1> are there?", while next query could be "how many <2, 3> are there"?

Comment: @bishop Essentially yes, that was true for the question up to update 2, but since I just added update 3, there are even more factors to take care off. It is... quite complicated

Comment: Even with your update, the combination point still seems to remain true.  If so, can you make `sourceItem`, `destinationItem`, and any other fields relevant to your counting bit fields?  That way, every possible combination is enumerated a priori and you can use a simple `WHERE`?

Comment: @bishop Could you please post it as an answer? As I am not fully understand what you exactly mean.

Comment: Are those `?` in your example query to be replaced with values selected from the interface as well?  IOW, they are also inputs to the counting query?

Comment: @bishop Yes, every `?` is to be replaced with *one* integer, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Ok, bit fields won't work.  If you are wanting real-time then, I suggest you go with a materialized view, eg the INSERT triggers you described.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Put your conditions in a `sum()`. Like this you get single counts

```
SELECT SUM(sourceItem = 1 AND destinationItem = 1) AS count1,
       SUM(sourceItem = 1 AND destinationItem = 2) AS count2
FROM trades
```

To get the complete conditional count do

```
SELECT SUM(case when sourceItem > 0 and destinationItem > 0 then 2
                when sourceItem > 0 or destinationItem > 0 then 1
                else 0 
           end) AS complete_sum
FROM trades
```

or

```
SELECT SUM(sourceItem > 0) + sum(destinationItem > 0) AS complete_sum
FROM trades
```

Comment: Unfortunately a `sourceItem = 2` can have an `destinationItem = 1`, but not `destinationItem = 3`, so I don't think the complete query will work.

Comment: "which means that every SELECT in the UNION ALL may or may not be there." <- I think that part essentially covers that.

Comment: Either that does not work like you think or I don't get you right. But I added another condition in my query.

Comment: I've added a more concrete explanation to the OP just now.

Comment: This query also takes 1.2s with an index on `(sourceItem, destinationItem)`, of course it's 0.0001s when you execute it twice, but that will not be the case in practice

Answer (score 0):

As you are always filtering by `sourceItem` AND `destinationItem`, adding an index on those two columns should speed this query up by a lot.

ALTER TABLE `trades` add index (`sourceItem`, `destinationItem`);

This way, the counts only need to get the values from the index, which will make your counts much faster.

Comment: Is there a difference between putting a seperate index on each of the columns, or putting one index on two columns?

Comment: Queries can only use one index per table instance. If you use a different index, the query will only be able to use one of them, forcing then to do a search on the other value. If you index on both of them, it will be able to use both.

Comment: Even then it still takes 0.37s on my original query sadly.

Comment: I'd say that's a big improvement. You can run an explain on your query (`explain <your query>`) to see how mysql is planning on running it, it gives you a better idea on what things to improve.

Comment: I don't think there's anything left to improve. I want to use this query in a live environment, so I'll need to come up with something better. (ps I did not downvote your answer)

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you? This query would give you the same desired output, with better performance.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
(
SELECT t.sourceItem, t.destinationItem, COUNT(1) AS count
   FROM trades t
   WHERE t.sourceItem IN ( 1, 2 ) AND t.destinationItem IN ( 1, 2, 3 )
GROUP BY t.sourceItem, t.destinationItem 
) as tbl_tmp
```

You say that you are running this query just to see if you need to display "No Results Found" message. If that is your only requirement, then I feel you just don't need a query at all. There would be other sources that could tell you that you something to display or not! Am I missing something here?

Comment: Takes 0.4s so a nope there aswell, I'm a bit on an edged blade though, I think I over simplified my actual question as it is actually much harder to compute as there are optional conditional parts aswell. I really think I need to store it in another table, holding the counts.

Comment: Do you really need the exact counts? We can simplify it further if you just need a 0 or 1.