# InnoDB and count: Are helper tables the way to go?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, triggers, innodb

Assume I've got an users table with 1M users on MySQL/InnoDB:

users

- userId (Primary Key, Int)
- status (Int)
- more data

If I would want to have an exact count of the amount of users with `status = 1` (denoting an activate account), what would be the way to go for big tables, I was thinking along the lines of:

usercounts

- status
- count

And then run an `TRIGGER AFTER INSERT` on `users` that updates the appropiate columns in `usercounts`

Would this be the best way to go?

ps. An extra small question: Since you also need an `TRIGGER AFTER UPDATE` on `users` for when `status` changes, is there a syntax available that:

- Covers both the `TRIGGER AFTER INSERT` and `TRIGGER AFTER UPDATE` on `status`?
- Increments the `count` by one if a `count` already is present, else inserts a new `(status, count = 0)` pair?

Comment: How often rows are being inserted/updated in `users` table? What are the valid values for status? Only `0` and `1` or there are others?

Comment: @peterm It is just a conceptual example, but an example could be status: 1 = ok, 2 = deleted, 3 = banned. And inserts would only happen every once in a while, updates however would happen quite a lot, but not on the `status` field itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Would this be the best way to go?*

Best (opinion-based) or not but it's definitely a possible way to go.

> *is there a syntax available that: covers both the TRIGGER AFTER INSERT and TRIGGER AFTER UPDATE on status?*

No. There isn't a compound trigger syntax in MySQL. You'll have to create separate triggers.

> *is there a syntax available that: increments the count by one if a count already is present, else inserts a new (status, count = 0) pair?*

Yes. You can use `ON DUPLICATE KEY` clause in `INSERT` statement. Make sure that `status` is a PK in `usercounts` table.

Now if users can be deleted even if only for maintenance purposes you also need to cover it with `AFTER DELETE` trigger.

---

That being said your triggers might look something like

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_ai_users
AFTER INSERT ON users
FOR EACH ROW
  INSERT INTO usercounts (status, cnt)
  VALUES (NEW.status, 1)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cnt = cnt + 1;

CREATE TRIGGER tg_ad_users
AFTER DELETE ON users
FOR EACH ROW
    UPDATE usercounts 
       SET cnt = cnt - 1
     WHERE status = OLD.status;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tg_au_users
AFTER UPDATE ON users
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NOT NEW.status <=> OLD.status THEN -- proceed ONLY if status has been changed
    UPDATE usercounts 
       SET cnt = cnt - 1
     WHERE status = OLD.status;
    INSERT INTO usercounts (status, cnt) VALUES (NEW.status, 1)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cnt = cnt + 1;
  END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

To initially populate `usercounts` table use

```
INSERT INTO usercounts (status, cnt)
SELECT status, COUNT(*)
  FROM users
 GROUP BY status
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1a40d/1)** demo

Comment: Is there any reason that on my database (10K users), it sometimes takes 0.03s, but occasionally 4 seconds? Or would the cause be somewhere in the shared webhosting.

Comment: Successive results from updating 100 random records: 0.03s, 0.3s, 0.98s, 0.07s, 0.20s, 0.82s, 0.09s. Might be the database?

Comment: For future reference you might want to explain what `NOT x <=> y` does, I just figured it out for myself though

Comment: As in any performance related question it's next to impossible to tell something intelligent not seeing and benchmarking the real system. Now it might be a drawback of this approach (lock waits) caused by concurrent processing "fighting" over these three records in `usercounts` table. Use `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` to check if it's the case. Here is an [article](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/08/02/how-to-monitor-innodb-lock-waits/) on the subject

Comment: Regarding the null-safe comparison: If one would explain everything in his answer then nothing would be left to catch the reader's attention... :) Great that you figured it out on your own.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are simpler options available to you.

Just add an index to the field you'd like to count on.

ALTER TABLE users ADD KEY (status);

Now a select should be very fast.

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE status = 1

Comment: I've seen cases a few hours where doing such sort of syntax on a slightly more complicated table cost my queries near 0.4s, I think `COUNT(*)` is a major culprit here, link to other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20924951/mysql-with-innodb-how-to-avoid-using-count/20925021